# Unity Editor Script, how to programatically mark a property field's value be changed

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I want to prevent some property field may change by the prefab's "Apply" button, Is there a way to programatically mark property field's value be changed (make it always bold)?

Comment: you mean make a property read-only but still display in the editor?

Comment: Thanks for your follow up, not read-only, I just want to make something like GameObject's position, It will store in the scene only and not to sync to other instance of same prefab.

I have a MonBehavior script named WayPath. It used to store way points for the NPC patrol. Obviously, WayPath should keep different in each NPC. So even those NPC used same Prefab, they should still keep the WayPath different, although I pressed "Apply" the WayPath should not sync to other instance.

Comment: Just make an Empty gameObject and set it's position?

Answer (score 0):

You need different instances of the Waypath so they're unique for each of the instantiated NPC's.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite interesting. I made a quick research to give you a good answer, but I just couldn't. Unity has not a built-in solution for this. It'll be useful for sure, but sorry no.

The only thing I found useful, but haven't tried myself is [this forum post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/specializing-prefabs-prevent-properties-from-beeing-overwritten.261998/). The author answers himself with a good piece of code for a workaround he is using, you can just adapt to your needs.

For simplicity, I paste it here:

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI ()
{
    serializedObject.Update ();
    DrawDefaultInspector ();

    SerializedProperty myProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty ("maxDistance");

    if (tick) {
       myProperty.floatValue = tempValue;
       tick = false;
    }
if(!Application.isPlaying)
{
    if (!myProperty.prefabOverride) {
       GUI.color = Color.red;
       tick = true;
       tempValue =myProperty.floatValue;
       myProperty.floatValue += 1;
    }
    else
        GUI.color = Color.green;
}
EditorGUILayout.PropertyField (myProperty);

    if (GUI.changed) {
        EditorUtility.SetDirty (target);
    }

serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties ();
}
```

I hope this is useful to you, due the date of the question.
Good luck!